# AAC format in Android

Tags: android, aac

I have a problem with audio on android.

Short Question:

I need to play and record audio in aac format an all Android devices.
I found that it is possible starts from API 10, but on my BLU device(2.3.5) it works by using `MediaRecorder` and `MediaPlayer`.
But on HTC Nexus One it doesn't work.
Have you any suggestions?

Long question:

To record and play audio in AAC format I'm using following code. It pretty simple and stupid, but it works for testing.

```
String pathForAppFiles = getFilesDir()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        pathForAppFiles += "/bla.mp4";
        if (audioRecorder == null) {

            File file = new File(pathForAppFiles);
            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();

            audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            audioRecorder
                    .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

            audioRecorder
                    .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

            audioRecorder
                    .setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

            audioRecorder.setOutputFile(pathForAppFiles);

            try {
                audioRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            audioRecorder.start();

        } else {
            audioRecorder.stop();
            audioRecorder.release();
            audioRecorder = null;

            new AudioUtils().playSound(pathForAppFiles);
        }
```

`new AudioUtils().playSound(pathForAppFiles);` - creates MediaPlayer and play sound from file;

To make it work on nexus I tried [aac-decoder](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/) - it doesn't play file to the end (plays only 6 second of 10 seconds file). And it doesn't plays sound recorded by code above.

Also I tried to install FFmpeg, but I haven't experience to make this library work.

So can you recommend something?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/

Comment: aac-decoder is a short version of aacplayer. It doesn't play aac file to the end and doesn't play sound recorded by device.

Comment: I found partial solutions. 1. On some devices audio not played because I'm trying to play it from files derectiory - data/data/com.myapp.player/files/music.aac. 2. On some devices it not working but aacdecoder can play file to the end. Just set to it small buffer size AACPlayer aacPlayer = new MultiPlayer(clb, 200, 200);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this issue by changing audio type to MP3, because some devices (like Kindle Fire) do not play aac from anywhere.

My recommendation is:
If you want to make cross platform sounds - use MP3. You can convert any sound to MP3 with [lame encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).